# How to install the R4 software for a DSi?

Tags: nintendo-dsi

I tried to install the R4 operative system from http://www.r4isdhc.com/r4-download/ following tutorials from several pages and it still doesn't work; when I insert the R4 with the Micro SD on the DSi, nothing happens, I don't see any launcher or something.

I guess that the problem is that the operative system isn't compatible or is just the incorrect one, but I don't know which I need to download, because the R4 has no tag, so I can't know the model or version or year of the R4

Comment: i edited your question as most of it had nothing to do with NDS roms but the R4 Software

Comment: Oh, well, thank you, I guess is more to-the-point this way